# Python if priorities and stopping a script

Tags: python-3.x

```
leftmost=int(input('Enter leftmost digit: ',))
if leftmost not in [0, 1]:
    print("You've entered a wrong value of", leftmost)
else:
    next1=int(input('Enter the next digit: ',))
if next1 not in [0, 1]:
    print("You've entered a wrong value of", next1)
else:
    next2=int(input('Enter the next digit: ',))
if next2 not in [0, 1]:
    print("Youve entered the wrong value of", next2)
else:
    next3=int(input('Enter the next digit: ',))
if next3 not in [0, 1]:
    print("Youve entered the wrong value of", next3)
else:
    print('Values entered', leftmost, next1, next2, next3)
```

Now this works if I enter 1 or 0 but if I enter 5 I get an error that the next variable isn't defined. for some reason python doesn't stop if conditions aren't met, is there a manual command to stop like return, exit or something like that? And whether this works or not depends on how much from the side ifs and elses are pushed. I'm an absolute beginner in this so be as descriptive as possible. thank you.

Comment: *“for some reason python doesn't stop if conditions aren't met”* – Why should it? It’s a sequential list of unrelated checks.

Comment: thanks, I guess I got it just by shifting everything to the side a bit, can you suggest any documentation for 3.4 python beginner?

Comment: @Saristas https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sneaking suspicion that what you really want is:

```
def enter_binary(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            i = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer.")
        else:
            if i not in (0, 1):
                print("You've entered the wrong value of {0}.".format(i))
            else:
                return i

digits = []
digits.append(enter_binary('Enter leftmost digit: '))
for _ in range(3):
    digits.append(enter_binary('Enter the next digit: '))

print('Values entered: {0}'.format(" ".join(map(str, digits))))
```

Note the significant reduction in repetition and improved error handling.

Comment: Thanks, I partly understand what this is, but this might be too complex for my teacher, it's suppose to be a simple script. :)

Comment: well, we're all starting from scratch, so this is too complicated for me now, but I've asked my teacher about while function and he was lost because we hadn't gotten so far yet. also, you should seek therapy you angry little man.

Comment: @Saristas if your teacher doesn't understand `while`, you might need a new one!

Comment: you're right jonrsharpe, he just doesn't code in python, so he learns something and then "teaches" us that, I'm hoping he will be changed for someone who actually knows python.